# Concurrent requests and shared HttpClient via ASP.NET CORE WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

If we re-use HttpClient like in SingleHttpClientInstanceController below , what if multi requests come in, and the current request is using the shared HttpClient, will this case block subsequent requests?

I have a Web API that accepts request, and calls external web services, if calling external web API blocks, will it block all in coming requests.

```
public class SingleHttpClientInstanceController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    static SingleHttpClientInstanceController()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    // This method uses the shared instance of HttpClient for every call to GetProductAsync.
    public async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string id)
    {
        var hostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
        var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(string.Format("http://{0}:8080/api/...", hostName));
        return new Product { Name = result };
    }
}
```

code above is from the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/

Comment: As long as you're not fiddling with any of the internals of `HttpClient` (changing default headers, switching out handlers, etc.) you should not have any issues. `HttpClient` is perfectly capable of making multiple simultaneous requests.

Comment: Why not adding the HttpClient to the DI Container ?